# Customizing Ubuntu 22.04 installer

Tags: customization, ubiquity

[image: INSTALLATION OS PIC]

I just finished remastering Ubuntu 22.04. Inside the customized OS, I installed a new Plymouth, changed the kernel, and changed the desktop environment from GNOME to KDE. I also modified the Ubiquity slideshow. Why does the installer show up named Kubuntu 22.04 and how to modify it?

Comment: The Qt *skin* of `ubiquity` is hard coded to show Kubuntu; which is why other Qt *flavors* don't use it; eg. Lubuntu (using LXQt since 18.10) has used `calamares` since 18.10, likewise Ubuntu Studio use `calamares` since they changed to using KDE Plasma (over Xfce).

Comment: Is there any other way to safely modify the os name without conflict with the system? im already tried to modify file /etc/os-release, /etc/lsb-release, /etc/issue but it makes the repository can't update the system

Comment: As stated the `ubiquity` is *hardcoded* to say Kubuntu when KDE or Qt5 is used, which is why the non-Kubuntu but also Qt5 or KDE *flavors* use a different installer.  Your alternative is to modify the `ubiquity` code and then compile & use your alternative; as stated in my first comment, the two *flavors* of Ubuntu opted to use a different installer. The `ubiquity` replacement `ubuntu-desktop-installer` does **not** have the hard-coding for Kubuntu with Qt/KDE so it's an option (*23.10 & later expecially*) which is what Ubuntu Studio plan using going forward.

Comment: can I use calamares instead? because never learn about qt. I understand the syntax but i don't understand how to compile the file.